# PHP - AJAX checkbox filter using data-tag attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, filter

I have `data-tag="Novel"`. When I tick the 'Novel' checkbox it will show the books that contain 'Novel' in the `data-tag` attribute. Currently the javascript/Jquery part works for `data-tag` that contains a single value but not multiple values. How can I make it such that for example there are two books of which their `data-tags` are `data-tag="Fiction,Novel"` and `data-tag="Non-Fiction,Novel"` respectively and when i tick the 'Novel' checkbox it will show both books or when I tick the 'Fiction' checkbox it will only show the books that contains 'Fiction' in the `data-tag` attribute.

Javascript/Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('.genre').on('change', function(){
        var genreList = [];

        $('#filterContainer :input:checked').each(function(){
            var genre = $(this).val();
            genreList.push(genre);
        });

        if(genreList.length == 0)
            $('.blItem').fadeIn();
        else {
            $('.blItem').each(function(){
                var item = $(this).attr('data-tag');
                items = item.split(',');

                if(jQuery.inArray(item,genreList) > -1)
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
                else
                    $(this).hide();
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="filterContainer">
            <div class="filter">
                <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="Novel" class="genre">
                <label for="check1">Novel</label>
            </div>

            <div class="filter">
                <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="Fiction" class="genre">
                <label for="check2">Fiction</label>
            </div>

            <div class="filter">
                <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check" value="Non-Fiction" class="genre">
                <label for="check3">Non-Fiction</label>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="booksList in fade">
            <?php 
            while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $title = $result['title'];
                $title = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', "", $title);

                $html = '<div class="blItem" data-tag="' . $result['genre'] . '">
                            <a class="blMask jt" href="readBooks.php?title=' . $title . '&id=' . $result['id'] . '">
                                <img data-original="' . $result['imageURL'] . '"
                                class="lazy thumb blThumb"
                                alt="">
                            </a>
                         </div>';

                echo $html;
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: What's not working in your code?

Comment: @Alessandro Niciforo It works for single values in `data-tag` attribute but can't get it to work with multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not far from the solution. You just have to loop over your `items`. First hide the element and then if at least one of the tags matches, show it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('.genre').on('change', function(){
        var genreList = [];

        $('#filterContainer :input:checked').each(function(){
            var genre = $(this).val();
            genreList.push(genre);
        });

        if(genreList.length == 0)
            $('.blItem').fadeIn();
        else {
            $('.blItem').each(function(){
                var item = $(this).attr('data-tag');
                var items = item.split(',');

                $(this).hide();
                for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
                    if(jQuery.inArray(items[i],genreList) > -1)
                        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

```css
.blItem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filterContainer">
  <div class="filter">
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="Novel" class="genre">
    <label for="check1">Novel</label>
  </div>

  <div class="filter">
    <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="Fiction" class="genre">
    <label for="check2">Fiction</label>
  </div>

  <div class="filter">
    <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check" value="Non-Fiction" class="genre">
    <label for="check3">Non-Fiction</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="booksList in fade">
  <div class="blItem" data-tag="X,Fiction">Item X and Fiction</div>
  <div class="blItem" data-tag="Non-Fiction,Y">Item Y and Non-Fiction</div>
  <div class="blItem" data-tag="Non-Fiction,Fiction">Item Fiction and Non-Fiction</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works somewhat but I think it only shows the last record. Even when I tick all the checkboxes it shows the last record.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to search on another array for an array.

Use a loop.

```
ele = this;
cond = false;
$.each(items, function(){
   cond = code || jQuery.inArray(this,genreList) != -1;
   return !cond;
})
if(cond)
    $(ele).fadeIn('slow');
else
    $(ele).hide();
```